# ''System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'string''

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

My Action method is given below:

```
public ActionResult Method()
        {
            var model = new PropertyDto();
            if (!Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("?amp=1"))
            {
                if (DefaultCityID > 0)
                    model.CityID = DefaultCityID;
                List<SelectListItem> Cities = cityService.GetMenuCitiesLite(1).Select(t => new SelectListItem { Text = t.Name, Value = t.ID.ToString() })
                    .OrderBy(o=>o.Text).ToList();
                ViewBag.Cities = Cities;
                ViewBag.CitiesIds = DefaultCityID;
            }
            ViewBag.Cities = cityService.GetMenuCitiesLite(SiteKeys.CountryID);
            return View(model);
        }
```

on the view dropdown list:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CityID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Cities, "Select city", new RouteValueDictionary { { "data-rule-required", "true" }, { "data-msg-required", "*required" }, { "class", "form-control" }, { "id", "CityDropdown" } })
```

Now on the other partial view where i am getting the data of cities via viewbag is getting an exception:

```
          @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Cities)
            {
                <li><a href="@(domain + item.SelfUrl)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double- 
                 right"></i> @item.Name</a></li>

            }
```

here i am getting the exception

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a definition for 'SelfUrl''
```

HOW CAN I RESOLVE THIS?

Comment: `SelectListItem` indeed does not have a property called `SelfUrl`.  What are you expecting that property to be and why?

Comment: `item.SelfUrl` <-- here `item` is of type `SelectListItem`, and you try to access `SelfUrl` from it, which does not exist. Btw, you'll have the same problem with `item.Name` below, as this property doesn't exist either

Comment: Also note that in your action method, `ViewBag.Cities = Cities;` (inside `if`) gets overriden right away. You probably need an `else` here

Answer (score 0):

`SelectListItem` which what `item` in `ViewBag.Cities` is, only has `Text` and `Value` and it doesn't have any of the properties you define on your models such as `SelfUrl`.

Simply don't use that model because you don't need it to render a list of links.

Use your own models such and initialize it like this instead of `SelectListItem`:

```
List<MyOwnModel> Cities = cityService.GetMenuCitiesLite(1).Select(t => new MyOwnModel { Text = t.Name, SelfUrl = t.ID.ToString(), Anything = "anything" })
```

You'll need to create the class of course:

```
public class MyOwnModel {
    public string Text {get;set;}
    public string SelfUrl {get;set;}
    public string Antying {get;set;}
    // put whatever you need here
}
```